# Error GCM on bitbucket - git-credential-manager: egg/egg-secure-memory.c:596: sec_free: Assertion `cell->requested > 0' failed

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-credential-manager

This error keeps showing when i try to push or clone a private repository on Bitbucket , even though works fine on Github. I'm using Linux Ubuntu 20.04.

`git-credential-manager: egg/egg-secure-memory.c:596: sec_free: Assertion cell-\>requested \> 0' failed.  Aborted (core dumped)  Password for 'https://JoaoVitorCafe@bitbucket.org':\`

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMDK4.png)

By using GCM i wasn't expecting to enter passwords or any king of tokens when using git.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you see a message that says something like "assertion failed", that means that the developer thought that that situation should never happen, but unfortunately, they were wrong.  That message indicates a bug, and you should report it to the maintainer.

There's probably nothing that you can do here to make this work, unless you want to try to send a patch, which will usually be graciously accepted.  However, at the very least, you should file a bug report, providing information about your system and any relevant details about your environment, so that it can be fixed.

Comment: Yeahh. You're right. The maintainers of GCM confirmed it was a bug. Fortunately, they will release a update to fix this on February 17.